# Django Image upload in project with two apps view not uploading files

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to upload images in a Django with two apps **home** and **main** my project name is register. Just to test if the media root is being added correctly I am displaying an image in my html template using:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}profile_image/profile_default.png " alt="HAHA">
```

However, I am getting a 404 error saying:

```
Not Found: /home/profile_image/profile_default.png
[02/Apr/2020 16:58:50] "GET /home/profile_image/profile_default.png HTTP/1.1" 404 8402
```

I already have this in my settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And I also have this in my project urls:

```
urlpatterns = [

 #my urls

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I am using the django_uuid_upload package.

For your reference my folders are

```
    register
     -home
     -main
     -register
     --settings.py
     --urls.py
     -media
     --post_images
     --profile_image
     ---profile_default.png
     -static
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error `Not Found: /home/profile_image/profile_default.png` shows that the URL is not referencing your media folder at all so the path is not going to your /media/profile_image/profile_default.png

The uuid-upload library sets the folder path to the `upload_to_uuid('post_images', make_dir=True` This sets it to the directory `dir/profile_image/`

Set that path to your media path then the profile_image path like this

```
image = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_uuid('media/post_images', make_dir=True),verbose_name='Image')
```

So that it works with your media folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does that mean the my media root directory is not set correctly?

Comment: try <img src="/media/profile_image/profile_default.png" alt="HAHA">

Let me know if that works for your image without the {{ MEDIA_URL }} tag. As if I remember correctly `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` isn't a valid tag by default.

Comment: Yes that does work but I was wondering why my images are not being uploaded to the media folder, is that an issue with my view?

Comment: This is caused by the behaviour of uuid-upload. 

upload_to=upload_to_uuid('post_images', make_dir=True),verbose_name='Image')

this will make it upload to a directory DIR/post_images/

Although I've never used uuid-upload myself you could try passing in the media to the upload string upload_to=upload_to_uuid('media/post_images', make_dir=True),verbose_name='Image')

Comment: Hi es I fixed that but it seems my issue is with my view I am trying to fix that right now.

Comment: If that was not caused by the changes from the original question then it would be better to make a new question focusing on just the new issue. Let me know

Comment: Yes I will add a new question focusing on that seems the issue is with the view.